# Seg Fault Error in C Program

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I had a program over 300 lines that worked 100% except for an fclose that caused a seg fault... Now, I can't even get my program to run at all. gdb gave me this error, which I honestly don't know how to interpret

```
    ____strtol_l_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=0x0, base=10,
       group=<value optimized out>, loc=0x349c78d580) at ../stdlib/strtol_l.c:298
       298       while (ISSPACE (*s))
```

Can anyone tell me what this means?

```
 readLinesFromFile(FILE* fPtr, int* num1, int* num2, char** strs, int lines)
 {
  int i;

  char data[50];

for (i = 0; i < lines; i++){
    fgets(data, 50, fPtr);
    strcpy (*(strs + i), strtok(data, " "));
    *(num1 + i) = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
    *(num2 + i) = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
}
```

Comment: Are you running Linux? If that's the case, please run your program under valgrind.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimisations enabled? You might get some more informative output by compiling with `-O0`.

Comment: Looks like you're passing a NULL pointer as the first argument to strtol.

Comment: u r trying to close the wrong descriptor

Comment: You need to show more code. It seems to crash in `strtol()`, if you're calling that it seems to be a good place to start looking.

Comment: I'm not calling that. It seems like the file PTR is misbehaving I narrowed down a spot. let me post it.

Comment: valgrind the code, you'll get the error on a silver plate

Comment: If you read the [this section of the GDB manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Selection.html#Selection) you will see the `up` command, which is used to walk up the call stack. Use it until you hit your own code, and start looking for problems there.

Comment: The error is with the atoi, but I havent the slightest idea why.

Comment: @Vlad - are you sure the input string has enough tokens for your code? Try printing `data` before entering the set of `strtok` calls.

Comment: I mean it should the input hasn't changes since the program was working correctly.

Comment: The data is correct, I seriously don't understand..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `SIGSEGV` is triggered when you call an `fclose`?

It looks like you're simple passing a `NULL` pointer as first parameted of `strtol` function (in some other part of the code)

Another option could be a stack totally messed up.

Try to run it with `gdb` and when it crash use the command `where` to see the stack